# How can I increment a UISlider which represents a clock?

Tags: ios, swift, uislider

So I have to implement the following:
[image]

As you can see the minimum value of slider is 10 min and maximum is 1 day.
So when I move the slider it should increment by 1 min(the label which says 10 min should change as u move the slider) and as it reaches the 1 hour mark the label should say 1 hour. Now, when you move the slider forward from 1 hour mark it should  increment by 1 hour and when it reaches the end it should say one day. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would translate the slider value to the time.

The minute range is represented by slider values [0.0 .. 0.5), the hour range is represented by sider values [0.5 .. 1.0) and the day range is 1.0.

So if your slider value `v` is less than 0.5, your minutes value `m` will be `m = v / 0.5 * (60 - 10) + 10`. If your slider value is 0.5 or greater, the hour value `h` will be `h = (v - 0.5) / 0.5 * (24 - 1) + 1`. If your slider value is 1, you just have 1 day.

As you probably won't want fractions like "1.63 min", you need to round appropriately.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but still doesn't work the right way, so when i move the slider from the start it reaches the 1 hour mark after 33 min which is not right, it should go till 59 min and then show 1 hour.

Comment: Ah yes - it was late and I made mistakes in the formulas :-) I'll correct them.